# How do I run a heavy cpu and memory HTML/javascript program? (firefox/chrome crashes)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

The program utilizes around 4-5gb RAM, causing both firefox, chrome and chromium to crash (not responding / "aw snap"). Neither Opera or Safari seem to work with the program.

I'm running a force-directed iterative algorithm. There are no infinite while-loops in the code, I've chunked the bigger for-loops into small pieces, so I have control to update DOM elements meanwhile.

I could rewrite all javascript libraries I use into making a C++ or Java application, but I rather not.

Is there another way to run this heavy javascript application?

Comment: Its really hard to reach 4gb ram, could you post your code?

Comment: If you profile the application, check for closures and try to avoid them as they are difficult to clean up. Avoid putting variables in global scope too as they won't be cleared out until you close the tab/window.

Comment: And @juvian is right please show your code.

Comment: Unless you're loading media files in to memory for some reason (bad idea) there's almost certainly something looping more than necessary. I agree with @juvian - showing some of those 'bigger loops' will probably reveal the issues.

Comment: I'm using more than a million data points that each have maps of 1-500 data points with vector positions and indices. And using octree to sort every one of these data points individually, creating a huge node tree. It's definitely not impossible to utilize that much RAM, I'm just doing it in the wrong language and wonder if there is a web browser that could support this kind of load. In Chrome it gets stuck midway in parseResult, in firefox it can handle first iteration of startAlgorithm...but it really is too much code to post here imo http://pastebin.com/TDjyhgPe

Comment: CPU load is only at 30% and I have 16gm RAM for usage. I'm not sure what options I have left other than switching language. I would definitely need a 64-bit browser afaik.

Comment: @user2010496 well, not sure what your program does, too many lines. Maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for this. However if you have 16gb maybe it's not crashing, it just stays unresponsive because of the time your script takes

Answer (score 2):

> > I'm using more than a million data points that each have maps of 1-500 data points with vector positions and indices.

That's really too much data for something that's basically a UI layer. The proper way to do this is to do the calculations offline and then write a server to serve regions/slices of that data to the browser. That's basically what Google Maps does.

If you want to stick with js then you may want to try something like node.js. Otherwise just use whatever other language you're comfortable with.

For that much data the only logical way to handle it is files. Read files for input and output to files that you may re-read from as input to more stages in the calculations. You may also want to consider using a database to abstract away the file I/O allowing you to concentrate on the data.

Comment: Upvoted - let the server do the heavy lifting and persist / cache the data so that it doesn't need redundant processing then provide hooks for a JS app to display the results.

Comment: Yea this program isn't going live, I'm both the server and client on localhost when executing this code. Sadly this is one of these algorithm where you need to put everything in memory. I read everything into the memory once, and output once, when the program is finished. It's not meant for javascript, just thought maybe there was a web browser that could handle it

Comment: I don't even need interaction with the DOM elements, I basically just need to brute force through this program and have an output tell me when it's done in console.

Comment: The hard disk is memory - just 100 times slower. However, for really large scale calculations scientists, mathematicians and engineers are glad to trade speed for making it possible to complete the calculations. You just need to be creative. And if you're not creative enough, as I mentioned, use a database.

Comment: Yea you're completely right. I think I managed now though in a the 64 bit web browser called Waterfox. I reduced the size of the octree slightly and got the 40 hour iterative process working just around the corner of crashing.